# Update MySQL database using an multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, multidimensional-array, mysqli

My requirement is to encrypt a password and update the MySQL database in one go.

This is how I tried to do this. But was not successful.

Is this a good approach?

php:

```
require_once("conn.php"); //PDO
//I've set all passwords in an array
$values = array ( 
    array ( "studentID"  =>  "SCI164" , "pass" =>  "ABCD12"),
    array ( "studentID"  =>  "GEO24" , "pass" =>  "XYZ1"),
    array ( "studentID"  =>  "SCI112" , "pass" =>  "PQR89")
)
foreach ($values as $temp) {
    foreach($temp as $key => $val){
      $stuID = $key"studentID";
      $rawPass = $key"pass";
      $encPass = md5($rawPass);

      $sql_update = "UPDATE students_db
      set pass = $encPass
      where studentID = $stuID Limit 1";
    }
}
```

Comment: if you're already using PDO, then use prepared statements, don't waste its good functionality, and if you're using PHP 5.5 use [`password hashing`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.password.php) or if < 5.5 use the [backward compatibility](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) instead

Comment: you should also read the note on the manual page for the md5 function http://php.net/md5

Comment: .. and maybe run the actual query

Comment: @Ghost: Thanks. This is to update a database which is already in use and has its own encryption series. I've used md5 here for illustrative purposes.

Comment: if you're asking what is a good approach, then use prepared statements. here a [tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use .**EDITED**
`$stuID = $key"studentID";` This should give error.

```
foreach($values as $key=>$val) {
      $sql_update = "UPDATE students_db
      set pass ='". md5($val['pass'])."'
      where studentID =". $val['studentID']."Limit 1";
      echo $sql_update;
    }
```

single quotes because md5 will return a value like `xvm456n334` i.e. alpha numeric.

Comment: `foreach ($values as $val) {` gives an error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH)`

Answer (score 2):

This query encrypt all pass value from `students_db`.

```
UPDATE students_db SET pass = MD5(pass)
```

Comment: Very nice. :) But there is a series of encryption happening. I've used only md5 here for illustrative purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I am not going into any security issues with any of this, I am not in a position to discuss it however your code should be like this:

```
require_once("conn.php"); //PDO
//I've set all passwords in an array
$values = array ( 
    array ( "studentID"  =>  "SCI164" , "pass" =>  "ABCD12"),
    array ( "studentID"  =>  "GEO24" , "pass" =>  "XYZ1"),
    array ( "studentID"  =>  "SCI112" , "pass" =>  "PQR89")
)
foreach ($values as $val) {
      $stuID = $val["studentID"];
      $rawPass = $val["pass"];
      $encPass = md5($rawPass);

      $sql_update = "UPDATE students_db
      set pass = $encPass
      where studentID = $stuID Limit 1";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this and you have to give `single quotes` around `$encPass` as pass column would have `varchar` datatype.

```
foreach($values as $value) {
    $stuID = $value["studentID"];
    $rawPass = $value['pass'];
    $encPass = md5($rawPass);

    $sql_update = "UPDATE students_db set pass = '$encPass' where studentID = $stuID Limit 1";
}
```

Comment: `foreach($values as $value) {` gives an error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH)`

Comment: try to check your array or update your question with new code.